# Corona SDK - How to remove an item(Coins) when collide with an object(player)?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, game-development

I started learning and developing games using Corona SDK recently and right now I am facing an issue to collect coins in the gameplay. When the player object collides with the coin object the coin should be removed/disappeared. I tried the below code which is not successful whenever the coin collides with the player it throws an error

> Attempt to call method 'translate' (a nil value)

Below is the code I used,

```
------Create Coins------

function coin()
token = display.newImage(sceneContainer, "gold.png")
token.x = math.random(320, 720)
token.y = math.random(160, 260)
token.myName = "token"
physics.addBody( token, "dynamic", { bounce=0, friction=1, radius=20 })

local function muovi()
token:translate(-2, 0) 
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", muovi )
end

tmr = timer.performWithDelay(5000, coin, 0)

------Collision Function------ 


function onCollision( event )
  if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
   if event.object1.myName == "player" and event.object2.myName == "token" then
      event.object2:removeSelf()
        print("hitting 1")
 elseif event.object1.myName == "token" and event.object2.myName == "player" then
   event.object1:removeSelf()
   print("hitting 1")
     end
    end
   end
 Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the gotchas in the [Corona Documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/removeSelf.html).

> As a best practice, you should set the associated variable(s) to nil
>   after calling object:removeSelf().
>
> When an object is removed, the rendering-related resources of the
>   removed object are deleted immediately. What remains of the object is
>   simply a plain Lua table with all non-display object properties — the
>   metatable is set to nil and all properties relating to display object
>   are removed. Thus, if there are still references to object in Lua,
>   they will simply be references to a normal Lua table.

Try setting the object to nil after calling removeSelf()

```
if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
   if event.object1.myName == "player" and event.object2.myName == "token" then
      event.object2:removeSelf()
      event.object2 = nil
        print("hitting 1")
 elseif event.object1.myName == "token" and event.object2.myName == "player" then
   event.object1:removeSelf()
   event.object1 = nil
   print("hitting 1")
     end
    end
   end
```

If you read the second point you'll notice that you'll still have a plain Lua table with all non-display object properties, so my guess is that it is calling removeSelf twice. The first time it is removing the object from display, but it's not removing the myName field. Therefore when it's called a second time, it's trying to removeSelf again.